# How to generate graph without taking of time using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have written a code for generating the graph and it is working correctly.
The problem is it is taking lot of time to generate. and i am not getting why it is taking time.
the code is

```
    Dim cc As Chart

    Set cc = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    Set cc = cc.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, name:=assume)

    With cc

     .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

     With .Parent

       .Top = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Top
       .Left = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Left
       .name = "cc"

     End With

  End With

  Dim sc As Series
  Set sc = cc.SeriesCollection(1)

  With sc
      .Values = Columns(b).Offset(0, -3)
      .XValues = Columns(b).Offset(0, -5)
  End With
```

Please somebody help me

Comment: well, it's hard to say why it's taking so much time, but I do see that you are using an 2 entire columns worth of data as your source. That could potentially be a big ask of Excel. Are you sure this is what you are after?

Comment: Hello Scott May be you are right But may i know how to select a particular data. I mean i hav data in colum "A" and i dont no how much it has so, it should select entire data

Comment: Well, then you should see dynamic named ranges. Or you can dynamically creating your range in VBA, so that you only get the rows in the column that have data. I can show you how very quickly, if you wish.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Please letme know

Comment: I posted an answer with the code syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, to just chart the rows of the column with actual data.

```
Sub makeChart(b As String, assume As String) 'i presupposed these arguments based on your code

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cc As Chart

Set cc = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set cc = cc.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=assume)

With cc

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    With .Parent

        .Top = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Top
        .Left = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Left
        .Name = "cc"

    End With

End With


Dim strValue As String, strXValue As String

'here you are using the passed column letter to find the specific column you want to chart
strValue = Split(Range(b & "1").Offset(, -3).Address, "$")(1) 'will return "C" if given column F
strXValue = Split(Range(b & "1").Offset(, -5).Address, "$")(1) 'will return "A" if given column F

Dim sc As Series
Set sc = cc.SeriesCollection(1)

With sc

    'will select from row 1 to the last true used row in the given column
    .Values = Range(strValue & "1:" & strValue & Range(strValue & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .XValues = Range(strXValue & "1:" & strXValue & Range(strXValue & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for above code it works exactly how i want
but can  you tell me how to add more series to same graph with same syntax for Xvalue and Values

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN -> if you have an additional question, please post a new question to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned off screen updating?  Add this to the beginning of your code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Then add this at the very end of your code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Hello I used above code It works good but its taking still too much time as Scott explained it may b because of selecting entire coulmn so itried to select only data in column that is 

    With sc
      .Values = Columns(b).End(xlDown)..Offset(0, -3)
      .XValues = Columns(b).End(xlDown).Offset(0, -5)
  End With

But it is giving error PLEASE HELP ME